# Align (overlap) two vectors that are slightly shifted

Tags: python, spectrogram

I am working on a software for spectral analyses.
Data consists of a np.array with spectral intensities, and a "wavelength vector" (wlv), i.e. the X-axis, so to speak.

When combining data, not all data has **exactly** the same wavelength vector, but they might be shifted ever so slightly, say by 0.00002 units or so.

Here is some  example data:
a (blue) is the "proper" dataset, while b (red) is slightly shifted:
a's wavelengths are

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].
```

b's wavelengths are

```
[-0.9, 0.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1]
```

Example

```
a_intensities = np.array([[2, 4.2, 5.2, 5, 4, 5, 2.8], [5, 5.2, 5.5, 5.4, 5.3, 5.3, 3.7]])
a_wlv = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
b_intensities = np.array([[1, 1.1, 1.7, 1.9, 1.8, 1.9, 1.2], [0.1, 0.7, 0.8, 0.6, 0.5, 0.45, 0.31]])
b_wlv = np.array([-0.9, 0.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1])
plt.figure('Spectra')
plt.plot(a_wlv, a_intensities.T, 'bo-', color='blue')
plt.grid()
plt.plot(b_wlv, b_intensities.T, 'bo--', color='red')
plt.xlabel('Wavelength')
plt.ylabel('Intensity')
plt.show()
```

Example spectra:

[Spectra images (updated)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCCQ6.png)

I now want to "shift" b's wavelength vector so that it overlaps with a. The shift needs to be conducted in the direction where the necessary change occurs.
Note that the wavelengths do not need to be identical (i.e. both be 0:7) but it is important that they **overlap** exactly.
Rounding to three decimals works in some cases, but not always (since I don't want to lose too much data), so I would like to have a way of doing this without rounding.

Therefore, in above's example, I want to shift b so that the bins overlap with a:

Before shifting:

```
a: [     0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6].
b: [-0.9, 0.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1]
```

After shifting:

```
a: [      0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6].
b: [-1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```

How would you go about this?
I am currently writing a rather lengthy function to do this, but I am afraid I am missing an obvious, much easier way here.

Edit: Some real-world data:

```
a_intensities = np.array([0.2184649, 0.2201522, 0.2186561, 0.2158286, 0.2134198, 0.2112872, 0.2141369, 0.2177338, 0.2169663, 0.2109826, 0.2084285, 0.2115282])
a_wlv = np.array([800.3474, 802.2759, 804.2045, 806.1331, 808.0616, 809.9902, 811.9187, 813.8472, 815.7758, 817.7043, 819.6329, 821.5615])
b_intensities = np.array([0.02411663, 0.02425605, 0.02463717, 0.02500274, 0.0251241, 0.02488419, 0.0243349, 0.02371608, 0.02327189, 0.023061, 0.023011, 0.02312733])
b_wlv = np.array([800.34744206, 802.27599007, 804.20453808, 806.1330861, 808.06163411, 809.99018212, 811.91873013, 813.84727814, 815.77582616, 817.70437417, 819.63292218, 821.56147019])

plt.plot(a_wlv, a_intensities, 'bo-', color='red')
plt.plot(b_wlv, b_intensities, 'bo-', color='green')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't understand the context where you're getting the data from -- anyway, is it guaranteed that both `a` and `b` are (sequence of consecutive integers) + (fixed small value)? (otherwise show some small real data)

Comment: The data comes from e.g. spectral libraries, hyperspectral cameras or FTIR instruments.
I have edited my question to contain some real-world data.